# SharedPreferences.Editor vs onSharedPreferenceChanged listener

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an activity that implements `SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_visualizer);
    mVisualizerView = (VisualizerView) findViewById(R.id.activity_visualizer);
    setupSharedPreferences();
    setupPermissions();
}

private void setupSharedPreferences() {




    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    mVisualizerView.setShowBass(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.pref_show_bass_key), getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.pref_show_bass_default)));

    mVisualizerView.setShowMid(true);
    mVisualizerView.setShowTreble(true);
    mVisualizerView.setMinSizeScale(1);
    mVisualizerView.setColor(getString(R.string.pref_color_red_value));

    sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}
```

I have an override method that listens to a preference change

```
    @Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

    if(key.equals(getString(R.string.pref_show_bass_key))){
        mVisualizerView.setShowBass(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.pref_show_bass_default)));
    }

}
```

I wonder what  `mVisualizerView.setShowBass(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.pref_show_bass_default)));` inside the override method does because what I know is that if we want to put values inside preference object is that we should use `SharedPreferences.Editor` just like

```
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
```

`setShowBass` is a setter method for the `mVisualizerView` not the method used for storing values that we want to save

if we want to retrieve the data we use

```
    sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, value);
```

why my code works without using the `editor` object for storing and retrieving of data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes everything you assuming is correct, and the code you shared is also correct.

```
mVisualizerView.setShowBass(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.pref_show_bass_default)));
```

This code is retrieving a boolean from sharedPreferences WHICH MIGHT BE SETTING IN from some change visualiser settings screen.

```
onSharedPreferenceChanged
```

is just an observer which is listening if any of visualiser/player setting is changed then update the view accordingly.

Comment: does `onSharedPreferenceChanged` automatically saves data based on users preferences and sets the mVisualizerView setShowBass without using `editor.putBoolean(key, value)? @Irfan Anwar

Comment: @code_noob no no onSharedPreferenceChanged only listen to any changes done by `editor.putBoolean(key, value) or editor.putString bla bla, you should see the function definition of  `VisualizerView.setShowBass.

Comment: onSharedPreferenceChanged is doing nothing, the code inside onSharedPreferenceChanged under `if` condition is maybe its doing bassView.hidden = false, and nothing more